# Does "rpm --test" verifies the dependencies too?

Tags: rpm

The manual only says "--test" only checks for conflicts:

```
hostname:~/foo# rpm -ivh --test jdk-6u2-linux-i586.rpm
Preparing...                ################# [100%]
hostname:~/foo #
```

**Our question:** does it checks for dependencies too?

Comment: I found a blog that says it also checks dependencies: http://zeusville.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/rpm-test/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add enough verbose flags to the rpm call rpm will tell you what it is doing during its operation.

So try `rpm -Uvvvh --test jdk-6u2-linux-i586.rpm` and look at the output for the `Requires:` lines.